# Use one dockerfile to build from two different sources

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a docker image using either git sources, or the already build app. I created two Dockerfiles like these (note: this is pseudo code):

Runtime-Image:

```
FROM <baseimage>
EXPOSE 1234/tcp
EXPOSE 4321/tcp
VOLUME /foobar
COPY myapp.tgz .
RUN tar -xzf myapp.tgz && rm -f myapp.tgz
ENTRYPOINT ["myapp"]
```

`myapp.tgz` is created on a buildserver or maybe by compiling manually. It is available on the docker host server locally.

To build directly from source I use:

```
FROM <devimage> AS buildenv
ARG GIT_USER
ARG GIT_PASSWORD
RUN    git clone http://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@<my.git.host>
RUN    ./makefile && cp /source/build/myapp.tgz /drop/myapp.tgz

FROM <baseimage> AS runenv
EXPOSE 1234/tcp
EXPOSE 4321/tcp
VOLUME /foobar
COPY --from=buildenv /drop/myapp.tgz .
RUN tar -xzf myapp.tgz && rm -f myapp.tgz
ENTRYPOINT ["myapp"]
```

The instructions in the second build stage of this are obviously a **duplicate** of the Runtime-Image Dockerfile.

I'd like to have just ONE Dockerfile, which can build from source, or from context on the docker host, as required. I could put the duplicated commands in a custom baseimage and reuse that to build onto (`FROM`), but this would obfuscate the Dockerfile.

**What is the recommended, most elegant way to do this?**

- I can't use a bind mount to get `myapp.tgz` in the current directory on the docker host, can I? For this I would have to start a `Container` to build my app?
- There is no `IF` directive in the Dockfile for conditions?
- If there is no `myapp.tgz` on the docker host, `COPY myapp.tgz .` will fail
- If there is no `buildenv`, `COPY --from=buildenv /drop/myapp.tgz .` will fail.

I could use `COPY ./* .` and then check with

```
[ -f /myapp.tgz ] && <prepare-container> || <build-from-git-source>
```

I guess? Our would you rather just create a seperate `Dockerfile` just for building from source and then use something like

```
docker run --rm -v /SomewhereOnHost/drop:/drop my-compile-image
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do seems to be to always do the build on the host; you could write a shell script that did whatever make process and then ran `docker build`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Unfortunately, some of our build servers don't support Docker (Windows Server 2012 and Centos 6.5) So I've seperate docker servers, where I can't setup Jenkins etc. (not allowed to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the past 2 days I have been trying to figure this out, now I have a good solution to achieve a conditional build (a `if` in Dockerfile)

```
ARG mode=local

FROM alpine as build_local 
ONBUILD COPY myapp.tgz .

FROM alpine as build_remote
ONBUILD RUN git clone GIT_URL
ONBUILD RUN cd repo && ./makefile && cp /source/build/myapp.tgz .

FROM build_${mode} AS runenv
EXPOSE 1234/tcp
EXPOSE 4321/tcp
VOLUME /foobar
RUN tar -xzf myapp.tgz && rm -f myapp.tgz
ENTRYPOINT ["myapp"]
```

The toplevel `mode` allows you to pass the condition with `docker build --build-arg mode=remote .`. `ONBUILD` is used so the command is only executed if the corresponding branch is selected.

Comment: Nice, I've overlooked the ONBUILD command in the docs. With this approach, one can easily add other build paths, e.g. download release binaries from a fileserver and use these as context (one of my use cases)